# mux_client_request_session: session request failed: Session open refused by peer

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-config

I use bitbucket to host some git repositories.

When I try to do:

```
git pull && git push
```

I get:

```
mux_client_request_session: session request failed: Session open refused by peer
ControlSocket /home/ravi/.ssh/sockets/socket-git@bitbucket.org:22 already exists, disabling multiplexing
```

Answer (score 12):

[bitbucket.org has intentionally disabled ssh multiplexing](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13465/please-enable-ssh-multiplexing-back), so edit your `~.ssh/config` file so ssh doesn't try to multiplex when connecting to it.

If you have `ControlMaster` at the top level of config, make sure it is removed as it supersedes any `Host` section configuration.

Then add:

```
Host bitbucket.???  # .org and .com
  ControlMaster no

Host *
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist yes
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p
```

Note that `Host bitbucket.org` must come before `Host *`.

Also, the `ControlPath` should only be writable by yourself.

Then, if the `ControlSocket` named in the error message is still there, delete it. (It will auto-delete based upon the timeout in `ControlPersist`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to change git ssh command in your local repo configuration and disable multiplexing mode.

```
git config --local core.sshCommand "ssh -o ControlPath=none"
```