# Move desktop files to a folder using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to make a windows command line script that moves all of the user data into a folder.
I stared with moving all the files from the desktop into a folder
Its working with xcopy but i revive some errors while using `move`.

```
@echo on
set SOURCE=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
set DESTINATION=C:\dir2
xcopy "%SOURCE%\*" "%DESTINATION%\*"  /y
pause
```

This works with `xcopy` but when I change it to `move` the syntax breaks.
Why is it happening?

Comment: xcopy is the right tool for the job. You can use move, if you wish to simply move an entire folder. However, you're not going to be able to move the Desktop folder. You can move folders within it though.

Comment: this may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743094/how-can-i-move-all-the-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor glitch in your code.
You can't use the asterisk (*) placed after the `%Destination%` while moving.
Instead use the following code. If you don't want a prompt use `/Y`

```
@echo on
set SOURCE=D:\old
set DESTINATION=D:\new
move /Y "%SOURCE%\*" "%DESTINATION%\" 
pause
```

Comment: Mark my answer correct for others to follow. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

For the **MOVE** command, the **/Y** option has to be specified *before* the source file names.

So instead, use :

```
move /Y "%SOURCE%\*" "%DESTINATION%\*"
```

Comment: this wouldn't do the job as `/Y` just suppresses the prompting.