# how to move particular selected files(JPEG Image) from one folder to another in windows 7

Tags: batch-file, command-line

What is the best command to move select files from one folder to another using command line code? 
other than normal cut copy paste

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move all the files from one folder to another using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743094/how-can-i-move-all-the-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

"Move"

```
move "sourcefilename" "destinationfilename"
```